# Empty Angular site after adding routes

Tags: angular, typescript, routes

I added `RouterModule` to my angular SPA application and after that my whole site just dissapear. After removing that from my `app.module.ts` file everything just back to normal state. Do you guys have any idea what is that happening?

Here is my `app.module.ts` code with commented `RouterModule`:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { NavComponent } from './nav/nav.component';
import { FormsModule, FormBuilder } from '@angular/forms';
import { AuthService } from './_services/auth.service';
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';
import { RegisterComponent } from './register/register.component';
import { UserService } from './_services/user.service';
import { UserListComponent } from './users/user-list/user-list.component';
import { JwtModule } from '@auth0/angular-jwt';
import { LikesComponent } from './likes/likes.component';
import { MessagesComponent } from './messages/messages.component';
import { PubEventsComponent } from './pubEvents/pubEvents.component';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { appRoutes } from './routes';

export function tokenGetter()
{
  return localStorage.getItem('token');
}

@NgModule({
   declarations: [
      AppComponent,
      NavComponent,
      HomeComponent,
      RegisterComponent,
      UserListComponent,
      LikesComponent,
      MessagesComponent,
      PubEventsComponent
   ],
   imports: [
      BrowserModule,
      //RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes),
      AppRoutingModule,
      HttpClientModule,
      FormsModule,
      JwtModule.forRoot({
        config: {
          tokenGetter: tokenGetter,
          whitelistedDomains: ['localhost:5000'],
          blacklistedRoutes: ['localhost:5000/api/auth']
        }
      })
   ],
   providers: [
      AuthService
   ],
   bootstrap: [
      AppComponent
   ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

And here is my `routes.ts` file that includes routing informations:

```
import { Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';
import { PubEventsComponent } from './pubEvents/pubEvents.component';
import { LikesComponent } from './likes/likes.component';
import { MessagesComponent } from './messages/messages.component';
import { NavComponent } from './nav/nav.component';

export const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent},
  { path: 'pub_events', component: PubEventsComponent},
  { path: 'polubienia', component: LikesComponent},
  { path: 'messages', component: MessagesComponent},
  { path: '**', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: null},
];
```

Comment: Did you add a <router-outlet></router-outlet> to your html?

Comment: Where should I add it? In top of app.component.html ?

Comment: Yes. You basically tell angular to display the route component in the place of the tag

Comment: @Akirus sorry for interrupting but in the moment when I did not notice that I still commented on RouterModule.forRoot, after uncommenting the problem still occurs

Comment: Could you try with pathMatch: 'full' instead of null?

Comment: Works fine, you are my God at this moment